# Insert/Update Data into multiple tables using NiFi in a single Transaction

Tags: apache-nifi, apache-minifi

I have to insert data into 3 tables which is coming from a previous processor and ,it must be handled in a single transaction . Can someone suggest a good approach through NiFi .

Comment: are commands to include into one transaction coming in single flowfile or in separate?

Comment: Use putsql or putdatabaserecord processor

Comment: @dagget 7 separate flowfiles.

Comment: [PutSql](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.13.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutSQL/index.html) supports `fragment.*` and `Support Fragmented Transactions` parameters that could force files to be processed in one transaction.

Comment: @daggett I am using that but the problem is ,it's not behaving properly ,sometimes it works ,sometimes not . And it is taking too long to process sometimes 5-6 minutes . Sometimes I need to stop and start Putsql to process flowfiles.

Comment: Edit question and specify all details for one case that works not properly. How many files,  what are the values of `fragment.*` attributes for all files in batch.